# The smallest primitive root modulo powers of prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, primitive-roots

I wrote a program to calculate the minimal primitive root modulo $p^a$ where $p > 2$ is a prime, by enumerating $g$ from $2$ and checking whether it's a primitive root, but I forgot to check $\gcd(g, p) = 1$. However, it still worked in all the test cases.

So is it true that the smallest primitive root modulo $p^a$ is smaller than $p$?

P.S. I think this should be right because the smallest primitive root modulo $p$ is $O(\log^6 p)$ (assuming the generalized Riemann hypothesis), which is much smaller than $p$ when $p$ is large enough. But I have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: Note that the smallest primitive root modulo $p=40487$ is $5$, but $5$ is not a primitive root modulo $p^2$. See also https://primes.utm.edu/curios/page.php/40487.html

Comment: There are $(p-1)\varphi(p-1)$ primitive roots mod $p^2$ and $(p-1)\varphi(p-1)$ elements mod $p^2$ are primitive elements mod $p$. Assume your claim is wrong: all primitive roots mod $p$ between $1$ and $p$ are not primitive roots mod $p^2$, but all between $p$ and $p^2$ are. Now take any, say $g$ below $p$, then its inverse $h$ mod $p^2$ has the same property, so $1<h<p$. But then $gh\equiv 1$ mod $p^2$ is not possible.

Comment: oops, the second $(p-1)\varphi(p-1)$ should be a $p\,\varphi(p-1)$, sorry.

Comment: Adding to the information by @GerryMyerson - the smallest (?) example of *some* primitive root modulo $p$ which is not a primitive root modulo $p^2$ seems to be: $14$ is a primitive root modulo $29$ but not modulo $29^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known, see

https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.11497

where it is show for squares of primes. Higher powers then follow from other elementary arguments

Comment: Surprising how much work needs to go in from $p^1$ to $p^{0.99}$.

Comment: Yeah, Paul Pollack has a very nice and simple argument which gets down to p no problems. It might be mentioned in the published version of this article ( somewhere in Journal Number Theory)